# Missing vector values when using envfit

Tags: r, vegan

I'm rather new with using vegan for analysis of microbial community data. I'm seeing a problem that the `envfit()` output doesn't contain any vector values, which are the ones I need for the plot.

Here is the code I used and the example files:

Code:

```
data.envfit.nmds = envfit(veganNMDS, mapping[, c("type", "location", "year")], permutations = 999, na.rm=FALSE)
```

veganNMDS:

```
Call:
metaMDS(comm = otu_hell, distance = "bray") 

global Multidimensional Scaling using monoMDS

Data:     otu_hell 
Distance: bray 

Dimensions: 2 
Stress:     0.1795224 
Stress type 1, weak ties
```

Snapshot of out_hell (there are a lot more columns and rows):

```
| |OTU1|OTU10|OTU100|OTU10003|OTU1001|OTU10016|
|-|----|-----|------|--------|-------|--------|
|Kras_10xS105_M01863|0|0.11208749|0|0|0|0|
|Kras_11xS106_M01863|0|0.12571412|0|0|0|0|
|Kras_12xS107_M01863|0|0.57184274|0|0|0|0|
|Kras_13xS108_M01863|0|0.07716415|0|0|0|0|
|Kras_14xS109_M01863|0|0.03789583|0|0|0|0|
```

mapping:

```
| |type|location|year|
|-|----|--------|----|
|Kras_10xS105_M01863|Hrast|B|X|
|Kras_11xS106_M01863|Hrast|B|X|
|Kras_12xS107_M01863|Hrast|B|X|
|Kras_13xS108_M01863|Hrast|B|X|
|Kras_14xS109_M01863|Hrast|B|X|
|Kras_15xS110_M01863|Hrast|B|X|
|Kras_16xS111_M01863|Hrast|B|X|
|Kras_17xS112_M01863|Hrast|B|X|
|Kras_18xS113_M01863|Hrast|C|X|
|Kras_19xS114_M01863|Hrast|C|X|
|Kras_1xS96_M01863|Bor|B|X|
```

Comment: This is a cryptic message: what do you mean with vector values and what would you like to find and where? Function `envfit` will return coordinates of ends of unit-length vectors (and with `scores` coordinates for the endpoints of vectors scaled to correlation). However, vector information is only returned for numeric variables. If you happen to have factors or character data (names), centroids for classes are returned.

Comment: Yes, I do get centroids class for the data, however I dont get any vectors information, even though, as far as I can tell I also have the numeric data (the otu_hell table). I would need both to construct NMDS graph later.

Comment: otu_hell data is used in NMDS, but for vector fitting `mapping[, c("type", "location", "year")]` must be numeric: they are the vectors you are fitting. Judging from names, `type` and `locality` hardly are numeric, and `year` may be defined as a factor.

Comment: Okay. Yes, the mapping doesnt have numeric data, as that is the metadata file (where, what and when was the sampling done), I though the numeric data refers to the OTU counts (which are numeric) in otu_hell.

Comment: You had used OTU counts in ordination (I guess), and vector fitting fits vectors onto that ordination. But if you want to have vectors, you need numeric vectors. Why would  you fit species count when you already had used them in your ordination?